# Dark theme of app

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xaml

I writing application for Windows phone.

I want to set dark theme of app.

I set it on this window, but when I deploy this app on device, my theme is light.

[Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yra3w.png)

Code of my xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Murakami.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Murakami"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="46">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/menu.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="46" >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/cart.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="63" Width="115">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/logo_murakami.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Is your phone set to light?

Comment: What is the `RequestedTheme` of your App class (in App.xaml)?

Comment: Light. Changed to dark. All Ok.